# TextBlock internal margin

Tags: silverlight

I suppose when several TextBlocks are located in a row(i.e in StackPanel with the Horizontal orientation)  they should look as if it was one TextBlock. But I found the following:

[image]

The first line is a TextBlock displaying "eeee". The second one is a StackPanel containing 4 TextBlocks and each TextBlock contains "e". As you can see from the picture above, the second line is a little bit longer than the first one. It looks like the TextBlocks have some internal margin. But, in my case, I'd like to prevent it. 
So, do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `Padding` and `Margin` of the `TextBlock` to zero.

```
<TextBlock Padding="0" Margin="0" ... />
```

Since you have multiple textblocks that you are going to want to do this with, you should probable use a `Style` to do this.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    </Style>

    ...
</StackPanel>
```

If this doesn't help, then you could start using negative margins:

```
Margin="-1,0,0,0"
```

However this introduces brittleness into your code, because the spacing between text depends on the font size and the text displayed. For example, if you change the font size to 13, you will no longer have this problem with five lower case 'e'. Changing the text to uppercase 'E' will result in the same problem, though.

You could try using the clipping properties on the `TextBlock` or even the rendering affects, but this seems like a lot of work just to get text to adjust a couple of pixels. May I ask why you are trying to get the two text samples to look the same?

**Update:**
I am doubtful that you can find a good way to make this work the way that you want to. May you should look into using a `RichTextBox` or creating a custom control.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426926%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is a good example use of a `RichTextBox` with text highlight (although it is foreground highlighting).

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be more complicated than I thought. I updated my answer with some comments.

Comment: The reason I'm doing it is that I'm implementing the HighlightedTextBlock control in which  some individual parts can be highlighted(saying highligtighting I mean changing the background color not the foreground) and it's going to be used in the item template for some listbox and the items will be highlighted dynamically to show the searched text. For some font sizes (as you mentioned the spacing between text depends on the font size and the text displayed) it's really noticeable that some parts of the items are shifted when the searched text are changed.

Comment: Generally speaking, I'm wondering if it's a correct behavior of the textblocks or maybe it's a silverlight bug?

Comment: It doesn't look good. I tried figuring out a nice way to get what you wanted with a standard `TextBlock` and I don't think you can do it nicely without extending the control. See my update to my answer.